# eJabberd admin panel not showing users

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module, ejabberd-api

In eJabberd API, Why eJabberd admin panel is not showing host, registered users and online users ?

Anyone having idea for the same ?

Because in Postman, all these type of APIs are working fine like connected_users_vhost, connected_users and registered_users

Please refer all the screenshots
[ejabberd_admin_panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liCQN.png)

[ejabberd_postman_connected_users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9ToK.png)

[ejabberd_postman_connected_users_vhost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0A31G.png)

[ejabberd_postman_registered_users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVfmA.png)

If anyone knows for the same then please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You logged in succesfully in the ejabberd WebAdmin, using an account that does NOT have admin rights. That is why no interesting pages are displayed.

Use an account in ejabberd that has admin rights (in ejabberd.yml), or give admin rights to that account.